# How to separate DEV and PRODUCTION environments in OpsWorks?

Tags: aws-opsworks

I'm looking for a way to maintain multiple environments (development, test, production) of the same application in OpsWorks. My application only needs a static config file after deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to just CLONE the opsworks stack after you've made it.

[image]

Once done, modify the application branch names ( if different for different envs )

[image]

If you're only needing to generate generate a specific config file for a specific environment, you could do something post checkout using deployment hooks ( [reference to deployment hook](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html) )

```
## deploy/before_restart.rb ( in your application folder )
stackname = node[:opsworks][:stack][:name]

if stackname.include?("dev")
  secret = "boo"

elseif stackname.include?("production")

  secret = "boo2"

else 

  secret = "boo3"

end  

file "/etc/website-config.conf" do
    content "password=#{secret}"
end
```